# Append to the end of a Char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a command that can append one array of char onto another?  Something that would theoretically work like this:

```
//array1 has already been set to "The dog jumps "
//array2 has already been set to "over the log"

append(array2,array1);
cout << array1;

//would output "The dog jumps over the log";
```

This is a pretty easy function to make I would think, I am just surprised there isn't a built in command for it.

**Edit*

I should have been more clear, I didn't mean changing the size of the array.  If array1 was set to 50 characters, but was only using 10 of them, you would still have 40 characters to work with.  I was thinking an automatic command that would essentially do:

```
//assuming array1 has 10 characters but was declared with 25 and array2 has 5 characters
int i=10;
int z=0;    
do{
    array1[i] = array2[z];
    ++i;
    ++z;
}while(array[z] != '\0');
```

I am pretty sure that syntax would work, or something similar.

Comment: There is no single complete type "array" in C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use C++'s string class (which is terrible teaching C++ imho), a raw, safe array version would look something like this.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char array1[] ="The dog jumps ";
    char array2[] = "over the log";
    char * newArray = new char[std::strlen(array1)+std::strlen(array2)+1];
    std::strcpy(newArray,array1);
    std::strcat(newArray,array2);
    std::cout << newArray << std::endl;
    delete [] newArray;
    return 0;
}
```

This assures you have enough space in the array you're doing the concatenation to, without assuming some predefined `MAX_SIZE`. The only requirement is that your strings are null-terminated, which is usually the case unless you're doing some weird fixed-size string hacking.

Edit, a safe version with the "enough buffer space" assumption:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned BUFFER_SIZE = 50;
    char array1[BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::strncpy(array1, "The dog jumps ", BUFFER_SIZE-1); //-1 for null-termination
    char array2[] = "over the log";
    std::strncat(array1,array2,BUFFER_SIZE-strlen(array1)-1); //-1 for null-termination
    std::cout << array1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about appending second array to first array, but you made a new array!

Comment: @MasoudM. the original question stated that two char arrays had to be added. There was no clear requirement of array reuse. Even with this requirement, this is a decent answer, because the "fixed buffer size" is simply not done in C++ (actually raw arrays in general). I added a safer version with the added requirements.

Comment: Ok, you edited your answer. but the original question was "Is there a command that can append one array of char **onto** another?"

Answer (score 5):

If your arrays are character arrays(which seems to be the case), You need a **[strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/)**.
Your destination array should have enough space to accommodate the appended data though.

In C++, You are much better off using **[std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)** and then you can use **[std::string::append()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)**

Comment: @TaylorHuston: I suspected so,Most of the assignment and homework related Q's have some strange stipulations of not using the features in C++ which form the very basis of C++,& that is the reason I provided both the alternatives.`strcat()` or [strncat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/) is what you should use in that case.Check out the link for usage details.

Comment: All these years, and still nobody has pointed out that when working in embedded environments the use of strings is considered harmful. And for very good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You should have enough space for `array1` array and use something like `strcat` to contact `array1` to `array2`:

```
char array1[BIG_ENOUGH];
char array2[X];
/* ......             */
/* check array bounds */
/* ......             */

strcat(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in command for that because it's illegal. You can't modify the size of an array once declared.

What you're looking for is either `std::vector` to simulate a dynamic array, or better yet a `std::string`.

```
std::string first ("The dog jumps ");
std::string second ("over the log");
std::cout << first + second << std::endl;
```

Comment: You can't even modify the size of an array *before* it's declared. The size is *part* of the type. What you're saying is like saying that "you can't change an int to a float after it's declared".

Comment: @KerrekSB An array type without a size is incomplete, but it's still a type. However, in that case you can modify the size once declared :D . Seems clear enough what Luchian is saying: a well-defined array object has an immutable size.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You're right, I forgot that you *can* actually declare an incomplete type with extern, as in `extern int a[];`. Good point. (But you can't *modify* the size, only *specify* it. That is, you can merely *defer* the decision.)